# When will Ash come back? [Spoilers]

Tags: mass-effect-3

Well, just started ME3, and Ash just got hurt pretty bad. She is now in the hospital on the citadel.

Just wondering, will she ever come back in my squad? And if yes, when? 25% in the game? 50%?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Virmire Survivor will return to your squad after finishing the Citadel Mission that occurs after Priority: Tuchanka. (This is relatively early in the game)

You are given the option to either welcome them onto your ship, or have them stay behind on the Citadel to coordinate the war effort.

Comment: Would you lose out on a war asset for choosing the former over the latter?

Comment: @Tristan Seems likely, though I don't know how much.

Comment: I'm more paranoid about screwing this game up than I've ever been with any game ever!

Comment: @Tristan don't worry about screwing it up, that's what replaying the game is for, its got a new game+ mode, remember :)